# How to get my graph in excel to only start on Sunday

Tags: excel, date, graph, excel-formula

I currently have a spreadsheet that has hourly demand data for an entire year. There are monthly tabs, and within each of these is weekly data. I type in the number of the week I want to view and the column only shows data for that week. I need to find a way to get make a line graph that always starts at day number 1 (Sunday), regardless of when the week starts relative to the first day of the month. For example, week 1 for some months begins with day 6 (Friday) of the week. I want to have a graph that starts at day 6, with nothing before, and has week 2 show a full week's worth of data. The last week of the month would likely cut off before the full seven days.

tl;dr: I need a graph that only starts on Sundays.

Comment: There's something contradictory there. In your example the month starts on day 6 which is Friday and you "want a graph that starts at day 6" - which is Friday, not Sunday. Perhaps you can show a more detailed example of the data (is it just a column of dates and a column of numeric values?) and what you want to appear along the x-axis (is it a sequence of consecutive days or a sequence of weeks?)

Answer (score 0):

Following the scheme:

[image]

Add the formulas:

```
E4 -> =WEEKDAY(A4)
E5 -> =ROW(A4)+(7-E4)
G5 -> =INDEX($A$1:$A$17;$E$5+ROW(I1)-1)             ' Autocomplete
H5 -> =INDEX($B$1:$B$17;$E$5+ROW(I1)-1)             ' Autocomplete
Graph Source -> =G$4:$H$11
```

The formulas check the first day of the table (A4), find the weekday (E4), find Sunday (E5) and generate the portion of the table in G4:H11. Only one week ...
In the same way you can add week or check the end of the mounth.